# Celery AssertionError

Tags: celery, celery-task

I'm receiving an AssertionError when running Celery. The issue is persistent and repeatable in that, if I run a job with ~700,000 subtasks, the issue occurs at some point well into the job. However, it does not occur if I run a job with only 180 subtasks.

```
[2014-06-10 10:27:51,355: ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: AssertionError()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/beccapetrin/Documents/Development/automated_reports/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 206, in start
self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/Users/beccapetrin/Documents/Development/automated_reports/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
step.start(parent)
  File "/Users/beccapetrin/Documents/Development/automated_reports/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 373, in start
return self.obj.start()
  File "/Users/beccapetrin/Documents/Development/automated_reports/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 278, in start
blueprint.start(self)
  File "/Users/beccapetrin/Documents/Development/automated_reports/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
step.start(parent)
  File "/Users/beccapetrin/Documents/Development/automated_reports/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 821, in start
c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/Users/beccapetrin/Documents/Development/automated_reports/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 72, in asynloop
next(loop)
  File "/Users/beccapetrin/Documents/Development/automated_reports/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/async/hub.py", line 324, in create_loop
cb(*cbargs)
  File "/Users/beccapetrin/Documents/Development/automated_reports/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/asynpool.py", line 263, in on_result_readable
next(it)
  File "/Users/beccapetrin/Documents/Development/automated_reports/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/asynpool.py", line 200, in _recv_message
assert not isblocking(fd)
AssertionError
```

Here are my config details:

```
$ celery report

software -> celery:3.1.12 (Cipater) kombu:3.0.19 py:2.7.5
            billiard:3.3.0.17 py-amqp:1.4.5
platform -> system:Darwin arch:64bit imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
settings -> transport:amqp results:amqp://username:password@localhost:5672

CELERY_QUEUES:
    (<unbound Queue automated_reports -> <unbound Exchange default(direct)> -> automated_reports>,)
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY: '********'
CELERY_IMPORTS:
    ('automated_reports.queue.tasks', 'automated_reports.queue.subtasks')
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT: True
CELERY_ROUTES: {
    'automated_reports.queue.tasks.run_device_info_report': {   'queue': 'automated_reports'},
    'uploader.queue.subtasks.multithread_device_listing': {   'queue': 'automated_reports'},
    'uploader.queue.subtasks.multithread_individual_device': {   'queue': 'automated_reports'},
    'uploader.queue.tasks.multithread_device_listing': {   'queue': 'automated_reports'},
    'uploader.queue.tasks.multithread_individual_device': {   'queue': 'automated_reports'}}
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE: 'automated_reports'
BROKER_URL: 'amqp://guest:********@localhost:5672//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: 'amqp://username:password@localhost:5672'
```

My worker startup command is:

```
~/Documents/Development/automated_reports/bin/celeryd --loglevel=DEBUG --autoreload -A automated_reports.queue.tasks -Q automated_reports -B --schedule=~/Documents/Development/automated_reports/log/celerybeat --autoscale=10,3 -Ofair
```

I run my application as a task, which then kicks off subtasks by using celery subtasks that are grouped together.

OS version is Mac OS X, version 10.9.3.

This seems very similar to some recent Celery issues I've seen on Github, but not exactly the same. Thanks!

Per a conversation with the celery team, am also posting the issue on Github: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2086

Answer (score 1):

This resolved when I removed the --autoscale flag from the worker startup command.